# Commit failed . exit code 1 GitHub Desktop

Tags: git, github, github-desktop

I am having issues when i try to commit in master using github desktop it shows me this error "Commit failed . exit code 1" i don't know from where it comes from because my teammates did the same thing and it worked fine for them but when i tried to push it, it won't work.

Comment: Does it fail on commit, or push?

Comment: when i press commit to master that error appear it's really weird only for me

Answer (score 4):

The reason you have this problem is that the directory you are trying to commit, has another directory within it with a .git folder. Perhaps you might have created a folder and cloned repositories inside it. Cloned repositories with .git folders will create a conflict.

**Fix:** Whichever cloned repository you have within a folder you are trying to commit, delete .git folder in them, leave only the .git folder for the main folder you want to commit to master.

Comment: You are a savior. I have been searching for this error for days.

Answer (score 0):

As the first answer by tavalendo says, its probably a .git folder inside a folder of the proyect, however its important to note that this folders are hidden, so you´ll need to activate the option to see this kinds of folders in the view tab.